# How to theme or override forms when using Panels

Tags: 7, forms, theming, panels

I am using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) in my website. there is a page `user/$username/edit` which enables the people to edit their profile.

I tried the following code to theme the `user_profile_form` form.

## Template.php

```
function MyTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    $items['user_profile_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MyTHEME') . '/template',
        'template' => 'user-profile-form',
    );
    return $items;
}
```

and in `/template` directory added the file `user-profile-form.tpl.php` with this code

```
<?php
print "Hello";
?>
```

After clearing the cache, I expect to see `Hello` message when I visit the user profile edit page, But I still see the same form as before.

I wonder why it behaves like this, I thought it may be because of panels module that does some thing which overrides my template file.

I would like to know am I right? or I am doing some thing wrong in theming the form.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try temporarily disabling the panel to see if panels is the culprit?

Comment: @BreakinIn Nop! but I saw many tutorials that do the same as above